# resteasy POST no suitable constructor found

Tags: java, json, post, resteasy

I have a RestEasy rest webservice where I POST a json with some data and the method has an object as parameter that reflects the posted data but I get the folowing exception :

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class si.arctur.webservices.OrganizationWS$OrganizationWrapper]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type infmation?)
```

The constructors are defined, I cant find the reason why no suitable constructor can be found?

my code is :

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response createNewOrganization(OrganizationWrapper organization) {

    .........
}
```

the object :

```
 public class OrganizationWrapper implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5931983940786473663L;

    private String idOrganization = "";
    private String name= "";
    private String address= "";
    private String zipId= "";
    private String zipName= "";
    private String province= "";
    private String country= "";
    private String registerNum= "";
    private boolean taxObligation = false;
    private String taxNumber= "";
    private String phoneNum= "";
    private String faxNum= "";
    private String email= "";
    private String webPage= "";


    public OrganizationWrapper(){}

    public OrganizationWrapper(String idOrganization){
        this.idOrganization = idOrganization;
    }

    public OrganizationWrapper(String idOrganization, String name,
            String address, String zipId, String zipName, String province,
            String country, String registerNum, boolean taxObligation,
            String taxNumber, String phoneNum, String faxNum, String eMail,
            String webPage) {
        this.idOrganization = idOrganization;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.zipId = zipId;
        this.zipName = zipName;
        this.province = province;
        this.country = country;
        this.registerNum = registerNum;
        this.taxObligation = taxObligation;
        this.taxNumber = taxNumber;
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
        this.faxNum = faxNum;
        this.email = eMail;
        this.webPage = webPage;
    }

    public String getIdOrganization() {
        return idOrganization;
    }
    public void setIdOrganization(String idOrganization) {
        this.idOrganization = idOrganization;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getZipId() {
        return zipId;
    }
    public void setZipId(String zipId) {
        this.zipId = zipId;
    }
    public String getZipName() {
        return zipName;
    }
    public void setZipName(String zipName) {
        this.zipName = zipName;
    }
    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }
    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public String getRegisterNum() {
        return registerNum;
    }
    public void setRegisterNum(String registerNum) {
        this.registerNum = registerNum;
    }
    public boolean isTaxObligation() {
        return taxObligation;
    }
    public void setTaxObligation(boolean taxObligation) {
        this.taxObligation = taxObligation;
    }
    public String getTaxNumber() {
        return taxNumber;
    }
    public void setTaxNumber(String taxNumber) {
        this.taxNumber = taxNumber;
    }
    public String getPhoneNum() {
        return phoneNum;
    }
    public void setPhoneNum(String phoneNum) {
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }
    public String getFaxNum() {
        return faxNum;
    }
    public void setFaxNum(String faxNum) {
        this.faxNum = faxNum;
    }
    public String getEMail() {
        return this.email;
    }
    public void setEMail(String eMail) {
        this.email = eMail;
    }
    public String getWebPage() {
        return webPage;
    }
    public void setWebPage(String webPage) {
        this.webPage = webPage;
    }




}
```

The json data :

```
  {"idOrganization":"2005032113214816","name":"Arctur d.o.o.","address":"Industrijska cesta 5","zipId":"5000","zipName":"Nova Gorica","province":"","country":"SI","registerNum":"5562325","taxObligation":true,"taxNumber":"76530566","phoneNum":"+386.53029070","faxNum":"+386.53022042","email":"info@arctur.si","webPage":""}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, the problem was that the OrganizationWrapper was an inner class defined in the same class as the webservice. When I moved the class outside of the webservice class it started to work. Don't know the reason for this but it is working now for me.

Answer (score 0):

How did you post that json to your API?
Please try to add header: Content-Type=application/json

You must point the content type of you request.

Comment: I have posted the contetn type of application/json, in the mean time I foud the solution...see my respnse